# How to take out input tag (Child) from the label (parent)

Tags: jquery, html, input, label

I have the contact form 7 plugin generating the following html code for input radio with the label text. I want to make the input field to be out of the label tag

```
<div class="radio">
  <label>
     <input name="radio-812" type="radio" value="nile" checked="" aria-invalid="false">nile
  </label>
</div>
```

I want like this

```
<div class="radio">
  <input name="radio-812" type="radio" value="nile" checked="" aria-invalid="false">
  <label>nile<label>
</div>
```

Can we do this with the help of jQuery ?

Comment: Is there a reason why you want to do this? It's generally considered a good idea to wrap checkbox and radio inputs in a label to increase their hit area for accessibility purposes. I think of a scenario where this would be a bad thing.

Comment: This is, of course, possibe with either jQuery or the DOM API ('plain' JavaScript). Where did you get stuck when you tried to write the appropriate script to do so?

Comment: The reason why I did was I have to make the input radio button clickable with image. Like this..http://jsfiddle.net/La8wQ/10/

Comment: Why does that require moving the radio `<input>` out of the `<label>`? Presumably you want someone to click the relevant card icon and have the associated radio `<input>` checked?

Comment: You are right !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use **[prependTo()](http://api.jquery.com/prependto/)** to move the input outside `label`, just before the `label` as you need. I hope this helps you:

```js
$('input[name="radio-812"]').prependTo('.radio');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="radio">
  <label>
    <input name="radio-812" type="radio" value="nile" checked="" aria-invalid="false">nile
  </label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
<div class="radio">
    <input name="radio-812" type="radio" value="nile" checked="" aria-invalid="false">
    <label>nile</label>
</div>
```

your code is working when you fix the closing brackets.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve what you want like this;

```
$(".radio").find("label").before($(".radio").find("input"));
```

But I don't see why you would want to do this, the markup seems fine the way it is.